# EKTORP and Spring in Linux sockets are not released

Tags: spring, sockets, ektorp

I am new to ektorp and spring. So please do not throw stones at me :). We have existing app written in php/couchdb and now moving it to java/spring/couchdb. I've followed the documentation how to configure and write the code. When I run junit test code works OK, but in the staging environment (Debian) I see sockets are not released, which leads eventually to too many open files error.
The DBConnection object is annotated as repository. I am not using ektorp spring and do not configure ektorp through context.xml

Here is the code to configure

```
private StdCouchDbConnector couchDbConnectior;

public CouchDbConnector getConnection() {
        if (null != couchDbConnectior) {
            return couchDbConnectior;
        } else {
            return createConnection();
        }
}

private CouchDbConnector createConnection() {
        StdCouchDbInstance dbInstance = null;
        if (null != host || !host.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
                        .url(host)
                        .port(new Integer(port))
                        .username(key1)
                        .password(key2)
                        .maxConnections(new Integer(maxConnections))
                        .connectionTimeout(100000)
                        .socketTimeout(100000)
                        .cleanupIdleConnections(true)
                        .build();
                dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                log.error("Cannot create CouchDB connection", ex);
            }
        }
        if (null != dbInstance) {
            return dbInstance.createConnector(dataBaseName, false);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned before the connection itself is working fine. The problem is when I run code in tomcat in stage environment sockets are not released and I see so many opened sockets connections with status CLOSE_WAIT and I know that they are stuck because process ran at midnight and I checked the system at 11 AM.
Here is what I see when I run lsof connand

java       604     root   44u     IPv6              53620      0t0        TCP ip_of_couch_db (CLOSE_WAIT)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update since my last visit. I increased number of file descriptors. App ran fine for a week then again it went over the limit of FD. Not sure what is going on. Checked all file reads/writes. All closed properly.